# Import liraries cause tkinter gui to stop working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently trying to write a simple GUI to help using a library written in python 2.7 I've been working on recently. I've started using Tkinter and I'm playing around with the basic widgets to get some confidence. I've noticed that if I try to import one of the libraries I wrote or even pylab the GUI stops showing even if I don't get any kind of error. I'm currently working under Ubuntu 12.04 and the code I wrote is something like this:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import read_Expe_XML as rxml #personal library
import write_Expe_XML as wxml #personal library

import Tkinter as Tk
import tkFileDialog

def file_open():
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    return

mGui = Tk.Tk()
ment = Tk.StringVar()

mGui.geometry('600x900+400+100')
mGui.title('Write Experimental')

mlabel = Tk.Label(mGui,text='Insert the .xml filepath:',bg='white') 

mlabel.place(x=30, y=20)
mentry = Tk.Entry(mGui,textvariable = ment, width=45)
mentry.place(x=210,y=20)

menubar = Tk.Menu(mGui)

filemenu = Tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label='New')
filemenu.add_command(label='Open',command=file_open)
filemenu.add_command(label='Save')
filemenu.add_command(label='Save as ...')

menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)

mGui.config(menu=menubar)
```

at the moment the GUI doesn't really perform any operation but I've noticed that if I comment the import of the two libraries I wrote and pylab the gui shows correctly, otherwise it doesn't. I can't understand why. Can you help me? Thanks in advance to anyone answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't produce a window even if you do comment out the `import` statements, because you haven't started the GUI main loop.

Add this to the end of your code:

```
mGui.mainloop()
```

Edit your post if the GUI still doesn't appear after that addition.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. As far as I know the .mainloop() is necessary for a windows operative system only. Under linux it should not be required, and I can confirm that the code is working without the import I've highlighted before. Trying to add the .mainloop() the final result is slightly different though.. I get a window opened in this case, but it's empty. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry I tryed again adding it at the end of the code (before I was just adding it at a certain point) and now it's working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2504163: you are incorrect. `mainloop` is required on all operating systems.